# What is the maximum size of an array while using Array.sort() method?

Tags: c#, arrays

in my application I have an array with 5000 elements. I have to sort these elements.But I am getting error of "Array index Out Of Bound Exception".
Can anybody tell me what can be the maximum size for the array to sort?

Should I use ArrayList ??

Comment: can you post your code please?

Comment: Could you please post the code you use to sort?

Comment: The problem is most likely something other than the call to Array.sort(). 5000 elements is fairly small and should not be causing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: This is not a problem with array size. The problems is in your code where you are accessing the array elements. Before accessing the array element check if the 0 <= index < array.Length

Comment: To all, thanks for your response..

Comment: It is limited with your Virtual Memory Size (if you set to automatic management then it is limited to your free disk space on the drive where your page file resides)

Comment: But code is too large to commnet here

Comment: @Mahantesh how? At this point the array **already exists**, and this is an in-place sort...

Comment: @Marc Gravell:What am i clarifying that there is no certain max limit for the array..

Comment: @Mahantesh well, there is the 2GB hard limit ;p

Comment: @ Marc, Mahantesh :  So, as per your answers I think that there shouldn't be any problem to sort 5000 elements... Am I right ??

Comment: @Jatin there *isn't* a problem doing that. My answer shows an array 100 times larger being sorted just fine. As I already noted, look at `.StackTrace` to see what is actually causing this;.

Comment: @ To all : I got my answer ... Thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no specific limit - you are only constrained by memory here, and at this point the array already exists, so this isn't a limitation of `Array.Sort`. For example:

```
int[] arr = new int[500000];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) arr[i] = rand.Next();
Array.Sort(arr); // works just fine
```

I suspect you might (for example) have an `IComparable[<T>]` implementation that is throwing an error internally? Or alternatively, perhaps this error has *nothing at all to do* with `Array.Sort`, and you have simply considered the wrong line as the cause.

The exception's `.StackTrace` should reveal everything, of course.

And no: you shouldn't use `ArrayList` here. Or pretty much anywhere else.